# Eigen vs QGenericMatrix

Tags: c++, qt, linear-algebra, eigen

I'm developing a Qt C++ application and I need to do some **linear algebra operations** and store **2D and 3D matrix data**. Maybe the **N-dimensional** case will be necessary too.

I saw that Qt have the `QGenericMatrix` class [(link)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgenericmatrix.html).

So, are there **any advantages** to include `Eigen` [(link)](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) in my project and use it instead of `QGenericMatrix`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really hard to answer your question accurately without more information. If I were you, I would take the decision based on the requirements of the project.

> Just apply the KISS rule i.e., **Keep it simple stupid**.

If your project needs to do complex numerical methods and linear algebra, Eigen would be a better choice. Otherwise you can just use `QGenericMatrix` or subclass it according to your needs.

It might be important to note that Eigen doesn't have any dependencies other than the C++ standard library and it is cross platform. So, using it probably won't cause any issues if you are targeting multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to give you an analogy, you are comparing a powerful and versatile toolbox (Eigen) with a simple screwdriver (Qt's class). I doubt anyone will be able to tell you what you should do based on the information you've given. A simple screwdriver may be enough for your project.

And it's unclear what you mean by a 3D matrix. Do you mean a higher-dimensional tensor? Neither of the two options can deal with those, as far as I am aware.

Comment: Eigen has a [tensor class](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support) in the unsupported directory. I'm pretty sure it's commonly used.